# Embed two iframes into html webpage

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to embed a google document and a google form into an html web page. I'd like to make it look like one page (doc on top, form below the doc) without the frames and scrolling bars. Does anyone know how to make this work with 2 iframe embed codes?

Thanks!

Comment: Google does not allow this. Read your terms of service.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t come on here often and just saw your question. I basically added 1 frame for the doc and set the width and height to 100%, and scrolling = “no”. Added a url at the bottom for the other document since Google won’t allow 2 frames. Thank you for all your help!